# why selected option text display null although i assign it on asp.net core razor page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I work on razor page asp.net core 6 . I face issue two properties `SelectedOptionValue` and `SelectedOptionText` display as  null on page model .

on page model I using hidden field to retain and store values of selected text and selected option id .

```
                 <select id="PrinterName-select" asp-for="SelectedPrinterId" name="selectprinterid" class="form-select" style="margin-left:3px;font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">
                        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                        @foreach (var printer in Model.PrinterList)
                        {

                            <option value="@printer.UserPC">@printer.PrinterName</option>


                        }
                    </select>
<input type="hidden" id="selected-option-text" name="selected-option-text" value="@Model.SelectedOptionText" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="selected-option-value" name="selected-option-value" value="@Model.SelectedOptionValue" />
```

on JavaScript i do as below :

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById("PrinterName-select");
        selectElement.addEventListener("change", function () {
            var selectedOption = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex];
            var selectedText = selectedOption.text;
            var selectedId = selectedOption.id;
            console.log("Selected Text: " + selectedText);
            console.log("Selected ID: " + selectedId);
```

**on page model two properties display as null value so
How to solve this issue please**

```
public ActionResult OnGetSelectedPrinter(string selectedtext,string selectedvalues)
        {
            string a = SelectedOptionValue;//display as null
            string b = SelectedOptionText;//display as null
        }
```

Comment: It seems you have the same question and the same code as this question: [How to store selected value id and selected text on two hidden field using razor asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76649559/8017690)

Answer (score 0):

From your question, `SelectedOptionText` and `SelectedOptionValue` get null value in backend. It seems to be a model binding problem. In Asp.Net core, Model binding based on the name of property. In your input tag:

```
<input type="hidden" id="selected-option-value" name="selected-option-value" value="@Model.SelectedOptionValue" />
```

You named it to `selected-option-value`, It can't match the property name of the backend, So when you submit the form. you will get null value in backend.

You can just use `asp-for` in this input tag:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.SelectedOptionValue" />
```

`asp-for` will Automatically generated `name` and `id` attribute in the input tag based on the property's name, So the above code in the html page will be transformed into:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SelectedOptionValue" id="SelectedOptionValue" />
```

If this property has an initial value, `asp-for` will also add `value` attribute automatically.

More details you can refer to [Model Binding in Asp.Net-Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Hi @ahmed abdelaziz, Have you solved this issue now?